# Passing by Reference with String Model

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having a problem with passing a String by reference for a function in Angular 2. I want to create a generic function that can alternate and blinking and Model by passing in a String array, an output string, and the trigger state for animation. However, the String is always passing by value. How can I work around it so it can pass by reference and change the Model in a component?

```
import { 
  Component, OnInit,
  trigger, state, animate, transition, style 
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('visibilityChanged', [
      state('true' , style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'scale(1.0)' })),
      state('false', style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'scale(0.0)'  })),
      transition('1 => 0', animate('500ms')),
      transition('0 => 1', animate('900ms'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  fancyText: {}
  isVisible: boolean = true
  fancyArr: Array<string>

  constructor() {
    this.fancyArr = ['Fancy', 'Text', 'Blinking', 'Alot']
    this.fancyText = this.fancyArr[0]
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.funcToTie(this.fancyArr, this.fancyText, this.isVisible)
  }

  funcToTie(textArr, outputText, stateAnimation){
    var curNewsIndex = 0
    setInterval(() => {
      ++curNewsIndex
      if (curNewsIndex >= textArr.length) {
        curNewsIndex = 0
      }
      stateAnimation = !stateAnimation
      setTimeout(() => {
        outputText = textArr[curNewsIndex]
        stateAnimation = !stateAnimation
      }, 500)
      console.log(outputText)
      console.log(this.fancyText)
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you are printing `fancyText`? Have you tried `this.fancyText = textArr[curNewsIndex]`?

Comment: Apparently I'm trying to make it as a standalone function (or as a Service) so other component can use the same function and print out its variable (or Model). So I don't want to tie this.fancyText (which is not dynamic). It works by that way, but I want to change it to make a dynamic function.